# Adding async await in node js

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am using node js function i have written the code long before but i need to add async and await in my functions i don know how to proceed with my code structure  .

Here is my code structure

```
app.express.get('/api/member/logout', function (request, response) {

        functionBal.logout(request.query.abc).then(function (result) {
            
            if (result) {
                response.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                response.status(200);
                response.json(result);
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
            response.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            response.status(400);
            response.json("Error   -- " + err);
        });
    });



module.exports.log = function (abc) {
    return new app.promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        functionDal.log(abc).then(function (result) {
            if (result)
                resolve(result);
            else {
                reject("Error");
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
            reject(err);
        });
    })
};


module.exports.log = function (abc) {
    return new app.promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        mySqlConnection.connection().then(function (con) {
           
            con.query("UPDATE member SET table1 = 0 WHERE abc = ?", [abc]).then(function (rows, fields) {
                resolve('success');
            }).catch(function (err) {
              
                reject(err);
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
           
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Please help in adding async await in this coding structure

Comment: If this is good, can we please close by marking as answer

Answer (score 0):

Give this is try.

```
app.express.get('/api/member/logout', async function (request, response) {

    try {
        let data = await functionBal.logout(request.query.abc)
        response.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.status(200);
        response.json(result);
    } catch (error) {
        response.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.status(400);
        response.json("Error   -- " + err);
    }
});



module.exports.log = async function (abc) {
    try {
        return await functionDal.log(abc)
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
};


module.exports.log = async function (abc) {
    try {
        const con = await mySqlConnection.connection()
    
        await con.query("UPDATE member SET table1 = 0 WHERE abc = ?", [abc])
        return 'success'
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Make sure, you have Node.js 8+.